# support lib android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout causes InflateException / ClassNotFoundException with app widgets

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception, android-support-library, android-appwidget, android-gridlayout

I'm having difficutlties to use the support library with `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout`. It always gives me following error:

```
    08-09 23:49:55.746: W/AppWidgetHostView(132): Error inflating AppWidget AppWidgetProviderInfo(provider=ComponentInfo{com.myapp.AppWidget}): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
08-09 23:49:56.716: W/AppWidgetHostView(132): updateAppWidget couldn't find any view, using error view
08-09 23:49:56.716: W/AppWidgetHostView(132): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
08-09 23:49:56.716: W/AppWidgetHostView(132):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
08-09 23:49:56.716: W/AppWidgetHostView(132):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
08-09 23:49:56.716: W/AppWidgetHostView(132):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
08-09 23:49:56.716: W/AppWidgetHostView(132):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
08-09 23:49:56.716: W/AppWidgetHostView(132):   at android.widget.RemoteViews.apply(RemoteViews.java:939)
08-09 23:49:56.716: W/AppWidgetHostView(132):   at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHostView.updateAppWidget(AppWidgetHostView.java:218)
08-09 23:49:56.716: W/AppWidgetHostView(132):   at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHost.updateAppWidgetView(AppWidgetHost.java:250)
08-09 23:49:56.716: W/AppWidgetHostView(132):   at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHost$UpdateHandler.handleMessage(AppWidgetHost.java:73)
08-09 23:49:56.716: W/AppWidgetHostView(132):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-09 23:49:56.716: W/AppWidgetHostView(132):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-09 23:49:56.716: W/AppWidgetHostView(132):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-09 23:49:56.716: W/AppWidgetHostView(132):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-09 23:49:56.716: W/AppWidgetHostView(132):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-09 23:49:56.716: W/AppWidgetHostView(132):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-09 23:49:56.716: W/AppWidgetHostView(132):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-09 23:49:56.716: W/AppWidgetHostView(132):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-09 23:49:56.716: W/AppWidgetHostView(132): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[.]
08-09 23:49:56.716: W/AppWidgetHostView(132):   at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
08-09 23:49:56.716: W/AppWidgetHostView(132):   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
08-09 23:49:56.716: W/AppWidgetHostView(132):   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
08-09 23:49:56.716: W/AppWidgetHostView(132):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
08-09 23:49:56.716: W/AppWidgetHostView(132):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
08-09 23:49:56.716: W/AppWidgetHostView(132):   ... 15 more
```

The mentioned line #33 is the part where the support lib tag begins. It looks like the class couldn't be found for any reason, but I don't know why...

The reason why I want to use this lib is because I want to stay compatible with Android v10. It does no matter wether I choose v10 or v4.2.2 as project build target. The manifest's `minSdkVersion` is set to 10. I followed all these [steps](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res) and also tried it with putting the .jar into the app's refferenced libraries and ticked the option to export it.

This is my `layout.xml`, which is being used to create an app-widget:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/appWidget_relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/appWidget_textView_profileName"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:text="profile name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/appWidget_frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appWidget_textView_profileName" >

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**UPDATE:** I managed to narrow it down to the usage of `GridLayout` in connection with app widgets. It seems, that this problem only occurs, when you use `GridLayout` on them. When I use the same layout for an ordinary `Activity` it works fine. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure the library is being deployed with your project? Depending on the version/ide/sdk you are using, you may need to check your project build settings (project properties, build path, libraries from vague memory). I think you need to make sure the support library is "exported"

Comment: yes, I have checked this option as already mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When making widgets, you are constrained to the `View`s that implement the `RemoteViews` mechanism. The way that mechanism works is that the remote, "host" process is the one doing the actual inflating. Therefore, if that remote process (the launcher that hosts the widget) does not have the `GridLayout` class in its classpath, there is absolutely no way you can do this short of drawing the View in your own process and setting it as a `Bitmap` on an `ImageView`. I wouldn't do that, though.

In general, when making widgets, constrain yourself to the `Views` that come with the framework.

Comment: So you want to tell me, that there is no way of using the `GridLayouts` in app widgets, even though the support library is an official part of the framework?

Comment: The support library **is not** an official part of the framework. It's an official part of the SDK. And no, there's no way unless you can guarantee that the widget host will have the class in their classpath.

Comment: And I suppose there is no way to tell the homescreen, to use this specific class(?)

Comment: No, it would have to be included by the author in the apk. (anything else would be insecure!)

Comment: Ok, then I will have to create two different kinds of app widgets. One for the v10 and one for all APIs > 10. Thanks for the advice, I already wasted a whole day on this!

Comment: `GridLayout` became available in the framework in API level 14, so that would need to be your cutoff point.